# How to execute a method on Windows Phone 8 every specific time?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to make Windows Phone 8 app run some method every specific time, like one minute? I want it to run only when the app is open, don't need background tasks. I write my programs in C#

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We cant help you if you havent try by yourself. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @aloisdg I've tried the method with DispatherTimer, but Visual Studio tells me that the namespace Threading does not exist in System.Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called a `DispatcherTimer` take a look at it here:

[MSDN : DispatcherTimer Class WP8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.95).aspx)

[MSDN : DispatcherTimer Class WP runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer)

Remember to include the

```
System.Windows.Threading  // [for Windows Phone 8]
Windows.UI.Xaml           // [for Windows Universal App]
```

Example from MSDN

```
private void Page_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    timer.Tick += 
        delegate(object s, EventArgs args) {
        //  code to execute
        };

    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // one second
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but Visual Studio tells me that the namespace Threading does not exist in System.Windows

Comment: @DominikMurzynowski Sure you are making a Windows Phone 8 app?  If that namespace doesn't exist, it clues me in thinking you are doing a Windows Phone 8.1 app instead.  If that is the case you want to use the namespace `using Windows.UI.Xaml`,  I will update my solution.

Comment: You're right, I'm making a Windows Phone 8.1 app, I didn't know that there is a difference. Thank you

Comment: @DominikMurzynowski no, if the updated solution above solved your problem, please mark it as so.